# respond_to in after_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, controller

I like to dry my controllers by placing reoccurring code in before and after filters. In my current project, every action has the same `respond_to` block:

```
respond_to do |wants|
  wants.html
  wants.js { render :layout => "transition" }
end
```

I placed this in an `after_filter` like so:

```
after_filter :respond_to_html_or_transition
```

But it leads to this error:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

This happens even when there is no explicit `respond_to` or `redirect` within the action. I'm assuming this happens because Rails (for lack of an explicit `respond_to` call) makes an educated guess and creates its own `respond_to` before the `after_filter`. If that's the case, is there any way for me to keep Rails from doing that and instead use the block in the `after_filter`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is not possible with an after_filter. The after filter deals with an already rendered action. At that point, the render have already completed (either the explicit or implicit render), thus calling render will result in a double call.

You can extract the code logic in a method and call the method. Another alternative would  be to make all the actions alias of a single action, assuming the body of the actions can be handled by a single method.

Last but not least, you can write a custom action responder and replace the default one of the controller setting

```
self.responder = CustomActionResponder
```

Comment: The last option seems like the best path, though I'm having trouble with the implementation. Overriding the `to_js` method with `render layout: "transition"` doesn't work. It renders, but it doesn't use the "transition" layout.

Comment: Just got it working. `render layout: "transition"` is fine. The real problem came from how I was assigning the responder. Rather than placing `self.responder = CustomActionResponder` inside the controller (which both you and several blogs recommended), I placed `respond_with(@items, :responder => CustomActionResponder)` at the end of each action. It's verbose, but it works. I wonder why the other approach doesn't work. I'm using Rails 4; perhaps its depreciated? Or maybe I'm not doing it correctly?